# Reset particular input filed

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to reset only a specific input field and display the placeholder on an event but not able to do, there are other methods such as initializing the input field with empty string but it do not display the placeholder as well as it is also a value which I don't want. I want to reset it with null value. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

it was quite easy, I got confused with empty value and spaces. You only have to do is give your input field some id, and create a button to click and reset the value. in the js, store the value in some variable and just initialize it with empty value when you click the button.

```
 const input = document.getElementById("input-value");
    const button = document.getElementById("btn");
    button.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    input.value = ""; //donot use this input.value=" ", use input.value=""
    });
```